# How can I rename a variable loaded in the environment in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

How can I rename a variable loaded in the environment in RStudio?

For example, if I have:

[image]

I would like to rename `data` to `data2` (without having to type R commands myself).

Comment: Can't be done. Sorry, but you are going to have to reach for that keyboard. R doesn't really grok renaming anyway, the way to do it is something like: `data2=data; rm(data)`. Note this doesn't create two copies of your data in memory at any point.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spacedman's comment:

> Can't be done. Sorry, but you are going to have to reach for that keyboard. R doesn't really grok renaming anyway, the way to do it is something like: data2=data; rm(data). Note this doesn't create two copies of your data in memory at any point.